# where not in () statement with lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

Does anyone any idea how can we use where not in() statement with lambda?

```
this is where id in() statement

public List<abc> GetList(List<string> ID)
{
return db.abcs.Where(a => ID.Contains(a.id)).ToList<abc>();
}
```

I'd like to find how cloud it be opposite.   "where id not in..."

Comment: You should add a tag for the language you're using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply add a not (`!`) operator:

```
// Not In
return db.abcs.Where(a => !ID.Contains(a.id)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, I thought it's not working with that way because I was getting some error. now I figured out it works.

Answer (score 2):

Why not ?

```
return db.abcs.Where(a => ! ID.Contains(a.id)).ToList<abc>();
```